# how do i get the highiest occured user in a table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

please I need help with this,
am building an app that allows users to send out invites, and I want to get the user with the highest sent out invitations, how do I go about it. my model is as below.

````
class Invite(models.Model):
    host_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    invite = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is import Count. Count the host_name of Invite() objects. And after get the only one host_name by ordering from reverse

Have Fun!

```
from django.db import Count

Invite.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('host_name')).filter(host_name__gt=).order_by('-host_name')[:0]
```

Comment: Thanks, Enes, I was able to achieve it using ur example

Answer (score 0):

here is the modification of Enes solution that worked for me

```
 user_with_highest_sent_out_invite = User.objects.annotate(num_of_invites=Count('invite__host_name')).order_by('-num_of_invites')[0]
```

however when there is a tie, it fetches the first object as specified above